# CSS equivalent of <big>

Tags: html, css, deprecated

What is the CSS equivalent of the `<big>` element? If I'm not mistaken then wrapping your text in the `<big>` element is not the same as setting a larger `font-size`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Google Chrome says:

```
big {
     font-size: larger;
}
```

That should be the corresponding CSS. Anyway, make sure not to use tags like `big` since they go against the rule which states HTML should be used to describe the content, *not* the appearance.
You could go for something like:

```
<span class="important-text">My important text</span>
```

And use this in CSS:

```
span.important-text {
     font-size: larger;
}
```

Which is the correct form, whereas

```
<big>My important text</big>
```

is incorrect.

Comment: Excellent, Thank you! the `<big>` element is deprecated. That's why I asked.

Answer (score 6):

This

```
<span style="font-size:larger">...</span>
```

is a direct equivalent of the `<big>`

Answer (score 4):

The W3C [says](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/graphics.html#h-15.2.1):

> **BIG**: Renders text in a "large" font.

So setting a larger font-size should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
font-size:200% = font-size:2.0em = <big><big><big>
```